# Expectation Value of Sample Mean

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expected-value

When deriving the expectation value of the sample mean, I am uncertain about the following step:

$E(x_i) = E(x)$

The context is the following:

$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}E(x_i) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}E(x)
$

Why is that the expectation of a realized value of the random variable of x is equal to the expectation of x? Should I be looking at each $x_i$ as a random variable?

Comment: They are most likely considering identically distributed random variables therefore $X_i\sim X$. Where X is the overaching random variable. Then $E[X_i]=E[X]$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be a sequence of independent, identically distributed (iid) random variables. The sample mean is defined by
$$\overline{X}_n = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\text{.}$$
Becuase $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are independent and identially distributed, we may, in performing probabilstic calculations (such as means and variances) use a random variable $X$ in place of $X_1, \dots, X_n$ whose distribution is the same as $X_1, \dots, X_n$.

That is,
$$\mathbb{E}[\overline{X}_n] = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X]$$
since $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is the same as $\mathbb{E}[X_1], \mathbb{E}[X_2], \dots, \mathbb{E}[X_n]$.

The overall point of this notation, in this case,  is to emphasize that $\mathbb{E}[X_i]$ does not depend on $i$ and is constant with respect to $i$.